# How can i center my v-img and v-card in a v-flex?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

**Summary**

I'm trying to display some album picture in a row in square shape *like in the codepen below*. Unfortunately, I'm meeting a problem. When the view change size in my browser, the picture should be separate by equally space, but it change when the view seem to be in `sm` and `xs`.

**Problem**

The space between the cards in the container seem to be deficient in `sm` and xs . You can see my problem when moving from `md` to `sm`. [Here the space between the cards are a lot bigger than expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gp2wi.png)Also, I feel that the card should be at the center of the view in those mode like it is in `md` and upper. 
[The card should be at the center, but isn't](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tzOo9.png)

**Tentative**

I have try to set my `v-flex` with `xs{size}`, but the `v-card` overlap each other when I'm changing the view size in my browser.

**Code**

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WqjrwK

**Expected**

I expect `v-card` and `v-img` to be separate by the same space in `xs` and `sm` as `md` and `lg`. Change the view size of your browser in codepen with the link above to see your problems. [The view as expected. It should be similar in `sm` and `xs`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/60zH3.jpg)

Comment: I am not sure I understand. Is the problem present in the link? If not, can you post the specific change to the code reproduce the issue?

Comment: I was very unclear so I clarify my question. I add pictures to be clearer.

Answer (score -1):

**Updated Answer**

You need the `v-flex` to have attribute `flex-grow-0` on size <= medium

And Parent div to have `justify-content: center`

The solution in this pic and in codepen here: https://codepen.io/meabed/pen/WqjgYL

[image]

---

**OLD Answer**

this is not an issue with the v-card, v-img.

This behavior is coming from vuetify.css lib, the padding changes from 24px to 16px

```
.container {
  flex: 1 1 100%;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 24px;
  width: 100%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 959px) {
  .container {
    padding: 16px;
  }
}
```

You can change this by overriding the padding to 24px in your own css

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 959px) {
  .container {
    padding: 24px;
  }
}
```

your codepen example https://codepen.io/meabed/pen/WqjgYL

Comment: I update my question to be clearer. It's was not the point of my question, but I didn't know that. Could be useful later! Thanks!

Comment: Got it :) i have updated the answer and the codepen as well :) - i think it works as you expect it! you need the parent div-flex to not grown on <= medium size and the parent container to justify center.